# ng-checked="true" being ignored on checkbox

Tags: angularjs

I have a checkbox whose checked state (`ng-checked`) is based on a computed property (`ng-checked="someFunction()"`).

For the sake of example, let's assume its check state should always be checked, ie: `ng-checked="true"`.

However, clicking on the checkbox will uncheck it, meaning there's a disconnect between the `ng-checked` declaration and the actual state of the checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="true">
```

**So why does clicking the checkbox make it unchecked if `ng-checked` is always true?**

[Demo Plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/yt9hc0fmJZsors8n5NVj?p=preview)

Comment: From the [doco](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked) ~ *"If the expression is truthy, then special **attribute** "checked" will be set on the element"*. It sets the attribute, not the property.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is the expected behaviour

Comment: @Phil, I'm not asking about any bound property, only the checked-ness of the checkbox, which is controlled by the `checked` special attribute.

Comment: Think about it this way; you have this HTML `<input type="checkbox" checked>`. When you see it, it is checked. You click to uncheck it. That doesn't stop it having the `checked` **attribute** despite it's `checked` **property** changing to `false`

Comment: Yes indeed. However I believe there is still value in the explanation you and the other answerers have provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ng-checked is not intended to lock the value of a checkbox, it is a one way binding which updates the checkbox only when the property its bound to is updated. Also you can not bind to primitives (in this case a boolean value), you must bind to a property of an object.

If you want to disable this checkbox, use the disabled="true" attribute.